# Class Diagram showing View classes

Tags: java, class, user-interface, uml, diagram

I have a confusion with the concept of the class diagram. Are we suppose to present GUI classes in the class diagram as well or is it just the models, interfaces etc. This is confusing because different people say different things. Can anyone give me a clear answer?

Comment: You are supposed to do whatever solves your practical problem. Do you need to show the interaction betweeen GUI classes and their dependencies? Then do it. Are you just discussing your data model? Then  do it.

UML is a tool. Use it in whatever way solves your problem.

Comment: @NickBailey UML is not a tool. UML is a language. There are certain tools that help speaking UML.

Comment: @Tomas Kilian a language is tool.

Comment: Yes you can model GUI in UML of course.
See answer here [User Interfaces in UML][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846323/should-user-interfaces-be-included-in-the-class-diagram-and-sequence-diagram/21980725#21980725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI classes are classes too. You can model GUI in UML in starndard way.
See similar answer here. [User Interface in UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846323/should-user-interfaces-be-included-in-the-class-diagram-and-sequence-diagram/21980725#21980725)